# Why does a Popen child process not die?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm launching a subprocess with `Popen`, and I expect it to finish exit. However, not only does the process not exit, but sending sigkill to it still leaves it alive! Below is a script that demonstrates:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import os
import time
import signal

command = ["python","--version"]

process = Popen(command)
pid = process.pid

time.sleep(5) #ample time to finish

print pid

print "Sending sigkill"
os.kill(pid,signal.SIGKILL)

try:
    #Kill with signal 0 just checks whether process exists
    os.kill(pid,0)
    print "Process still alive immediately after (not so bad...)!"
except Exception as e:
    print "Succeeded in terminating child quickly!"

time.sleep(20) #Give it ample time to die

#Kill with signal 0 just checks whether process exists
try:
    os.kill(pid,0)
    print "Process still alive! That's bad!"
except Exception as e:
    print "Succeeded in terminating child!"
```

For me, this prints:

```
77881
Python 2.7.10
Sending sigkill
Process still alive immediately after (not so bad...)!
Process still alive! That's bad!
```

Not only can this script verify that the child is still alive after it should have finished, but I can use `ps` on the process id that's printed and see that it still exists. Oddly, ps lists the process name as `(Python)` (note the parenthesis).

Comment: Why not `process.terminate()`?

Comment: It's a zombie process.  It won't go away until you call [`os.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.wait).

Comment: @Kevin: Yup, that was it! If you post this as an answer, I'll choose it.

Comment: @zwer: This is a simplified version of what I was actually trying to do. In the actual program, the part initiating the termination only knows the child pid, it doesn't have access to the `process` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either call [`process.wait()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait), or use [`signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_IGN)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal) once to indicate that you don't intend to wait for any children.  The former is portable; the latter only works on Unix (but is [POSIX-standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html#tag_16_01_03_01)).  If you do neither of these things, on Unix the process will hang around as a zombie, and Windows [has a similar behavior if you keep the process handle open](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040723-00/?p=38363).